# The meaning of しなければならず in this article

Tags: meaning, auxiliary-ず

What's the meaning of しなければならず in this article?

> 「拘束中に、事情があってイスラム教に**改宗しなければならず**、そこで自分で『ウマル』というのを選んでいた。彼らが設定したルールに従って言った」と説明し

[link to the original and complete phrase](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20181025/k10011684931000.html?utm_int=all_side_ranking-social_003)

Comment: 「しなければならない」は分かります？

Comment: Yes, but why the "zu" at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

しなければならず literally means "have to do~~ and..." "must do~~ and..."

The ず is the continuative form (連用形) of the classical negative auxiliary ぬ, which corresponds to the negative auxiliary ない in modern Japanese.

Basically:

しなければならぬ (しなければならない in modern Japanese) ← terminal form (終止形)
しなければならず (しなければならなく(て)* in modern Japanese) ← continuative form (連用形)

<sub>*しなければならず is still used mainly in writing and formal speech. We also use しなければいけなくて、しなくてはいけなくて、しないといけなくて、しなくてはならなくて, or more colloquially しなきゃいけなくて、しなくちゃいけなくて, etc.</sub>

> 拘束中に、事情があってイスラム教に改宗**しなければならず、**そこで自分で『ウマル』というのを選んでいた。
>   During detention, due to the circumstances / for reasons I **had to** convert to Islam, **and** at that time I chose the name 'Umar' for myself.

<sub>(If you were to split the sentence into two, you'd say like 拘束中に、事情があってイスラム教に改宗**しなければならなかった。そして**そこで自分で『ウマル』というのを選んでいた。)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

しなければならず stands for しなければならない 
It means ( must).